# How I can locate page in jquery ajax if php return location header?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I send a form with jquery ajax like this:

```
$("#login").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();             
    var url = "login";
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success:function(result){
        $("#response").text(result)
});});
```

I wanna locate page if login was successful.
This is my php condition:

```
    if(islogin())
        header("Location:".$home_url."home");   
    }
    else{
        echo "Oops! Something is wrong!";
    }
```

How can I change my jquery script to locate page? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ajax success statements with:

```
success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Location'));
}
```

So your complete script would be:

```
$("#login").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();          
    var url = "login";
    $.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:'POST',
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Location'));
    }
});});
```

And your php script would change to:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location");
if(islogin())
    echo $home_url."home";
}
else{
    echo "Oops! Something is wrong!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. but How this  show error message if not login success?

Comment: Add the following header in your php and everything should be just fine: `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location`

Comment: And test the location header instead of just console log it

Comment: @Pk19000 Answer Updated!

Comment: Try checking for status code instead, `if(xhr.status === 302)` and then get the value using `xhr.getResponseHeader('Location')`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

JS

```
$("#login").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();             
    var url = "login";
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success:function(result){
            if (result.indexOf('Oops') !=-1) {
               $("#response").text(result)
            } else {
               window.location.href = result;
            }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
if(islogin())
    echo $home_url."home";
}
else{
    echo "Oops! Something is wrong!";
}
```

Comment: Tnx. but if  I don't want change my backend script how can I do this? I don't want to compare result strings. maybe user change theme!

Comment: Is a problem, because this line "header("Location:".$home_url."home");" not return any value and can't change any to the main page, is an async request.

Comment: So how can do this without compare string? If I change my backend script?

Comment: If your problem is the security, you can't resolve the problem here ! you can add a SESSION variable in PHP for login or error login and check if SESSION is set on the private pages, and if not force redirect the user to the login page (with php command!). The client side is ever a risk, server side is your secure code where check and block the user !

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use Ajax at all if you change the page anyway?

If you still want to, echo the actual new location instead of setting a header and do

```
success:function(result){
  if (result.indexOf("Oops") !=-1) $("#response").text(result);
  else location.replace(result);
});
```

Comment: Seems like he only wants to change the page when the login succeeds, making it a requierment to use AJAX.

Comment: Tnx. but if I don't want change my backend script how can I do this? I don't want to compare result strings. maybe user change theme!